# How can I perform a regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using Python to create an excel file from a csv file. I am trying to get it to where if the data for the cell begins with a "=" then print it as a function in excel... but i'm not having any luck. I tried to perform a regex on the string to see if it starts with a "=" but it isn't working. Here is what I have so far in Python:

```
import xlwt
import re

string = '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com";"Google")'

if re.match("^=", string) == True:
    formData = re.sub('=', '', string)
    sheet.write(row_count,col-1, Formula("'" + formDta + "'"),style)
```

Is this not the right approach, or am I just have the wrong syntax? Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need regex for this. Something like: `if string.startswith('='): do something` would be fine.

That said, here's an excerpt from the [Python documentation for the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: match checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while search checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).

Which is to say that if you're using `re.match()`, the `^` start-of-line anchor is not necessary.

EDIT: @aix is correct about the behaviour of `re.match()` - it will only match the pattern to an entire line (not part thereof.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're comparing against `True`. Python's `True` is a boolean object. `re.match()` returns a `match` object. When Python compares the two, the types don't match, and the `if` test fails.

The idiomatic way to do a regexp test in python is with:

```
if re.match(regexp, string):
```

Python treats most non-`False`, non-`None` values as true, for the purposes of `if` and `while` tests. The above code uses that behavior - if the regex matches, a `match` object is returned and the test passes. If the regex does not match, `None` is returned and the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com";"Google")'

if s.startswith('='):
   ...
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that `re.match()` only returns `True` if the entire input string matches the regex. In your case, only the first character does. You could either use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search), or change the regex to `"^=.*"`. However, I think that `startswith()` is a better approach.

P.S. I've renamed your variable so that it doesn't shadow the standard [`string`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) module.